# deceptive digital signature?

Tags: certificates, digital-signature, pdf

I am new to cyphering and I try to understand this case :

my government sends me so-called "digitally signed" PDFs, as you can see below (text only, after "Thanks").  Although there is a certificate reference and a signature string at the end, Acrobat reader does not see the PDF file as digitally signed.

Inversely, I have tried Acrobat reader on a digitally signed PDF sample and it was indeed detected and validated, after certificate import.

Even though the government could check the signature privately, I cannot, which is not only UNFAIR (since I depend on the government good will) but also INSECURE, because nobody except the government can detect fakes.

Am I correct ?

Thanks.

---

> DIR REGION FINANCES PUBLIQUES MIDI-PYRENEES ET HAUTE-GARONNE 34 RUE DES LOIS
>   31039 TOULOUSE CEDEX9
>   Accueil du public :
>   Horaires sur impôts.gouv.fr rubrique nous contacter.
>   Téléphone : 05 61 10 67 00 DRFIP31@DGFIP.FINANCES.GOUV.FR
>     M ***** Françoise, merci d'avoir déposé la déclaration de l'entreprise MME ***** FRANCOISE, SIREN *****.
>   Cet accusé de réception est délivré et signé électroniquement par l'Administration fiscale. Il établit que vous avez déposé votre déclaration aux jour et heure indiqués dans la rubrique "Date de dépôt".
>   Cet accusé de réception est opposable à l'administration à condition que les informations contenues dans le cadre intitulé "Accusé de réception signé" ci-dessous soient conservées sans aucune modification.
>        ACCUSE DE RECEPTION SIGNE
>       Informations sur le document signé
>   Procédure : Déclaration de TVA
>   Formulaire principal : 3310CA3
>   Période déclarée : Octobre 2015
>   Date limite de dépôt : 19/11/2015
>   Numéro de dépôt : TVA-2015305-0000000059381832
>   Date de dépôt : 01 novembre 2015 à 22:29:07 (heure de Paris) Désignation du soumissionnaire : MME ***** FRANCOISE Identifiant du soumissionnaire : 794378356
>   Désignation du signataire : ***** Françoise
>   Synthèse des éléments déclarés : Total général de la TVA brute due sur opérations imposables et
>   régularisations : 300
>   Total de la TVA déductible : 7 TVA nette due : 293
>   Total à payer : 293
>                  Signature de l'administration
>    Désignation : Signature numérique :
>   DIRECTION GENERALE DES FINANCES PUBLIQUES - Production (certificat n°
>   1579453858693123235869248904682000867904240)
>   [DYIDuGoS8A8eWtpesvAHVt9dtFa2cnwRlc3QHqz8XcTFPrQqkFhkYzBXWmz9Rm2PJ9QkMi23j6
>   DAtuzKq4/6U9eeLhgGUJXjWpzOkdn4E0SPnfFIwmEOa36tnrmNoyjHPo02+bjPN+ETBum4bbYxV
>   JNZz4Cp8/gLAzdnl2bac7yhQQvbviJpW9QXiDgOHr4GN6kp5OaPvJgIi8QYKuVqeJs9EvXLGpoz
>   tWOlpE4K5jbCddD/u2ahmrvrcP5iDtUUAqYUQ2vSVjwYKahB9L29xTZGr4SbQWb7+KQKSvdsZ+o
>   KQqsJS7qdgJmOWFYVo8wz9gQ9I4eX/mxjpc83oYtlHQ==]

Comment: `unfair` is not really on topic for this site.

Comment: Adobe isn't a gold standard for digital signatures. It accepts certain methods.  What digital signature system is France using?  You should be able to find this on their info sites or request it by phone.

Comment: There nothing special in French law.  Digital signature is a proof before courts as soon as it garantees authenticity, integrity.  You can achieve these conditions freely.  This is a case of non symmetric signature : only one signer can check.  It coud be improved but it is better than no signature at all.